# Is there some feasible optimization solution based on fuzzy matching of two Spark tables

Tags: sql, apache-spark

## Question

I have a table that needs to be filtered.

There are a lot of conditions, about `12,000`, and they are **fuzzy matches**, stored in the Mysql located. (We usually think of having `where-like` to complete the matching, but this time there are just too many conditions).

## Difficulty

For some special reason, I could **only do the job using SQL on Spark** (no Java or Scala code could be written).

Putting like in the Join condition does get the desired result.

```sql
SELECT a,b,c FROM tb1 JOIN tb2 ON tb1.a like '%' + tb2.a + '%'
```

> I have added `%` to the data in Mysql. The purpose of presenting the SQL this way is to convey that all matches are **inclusive-matches**

I know this SQL looks very bad, but it's the simplest one that meets the requirements.

Are there any feasible **optimizations** based on this environment?

## Additional

Also, if it is possible to write Spark code, is there a feasible optimization solution?

> The solution I have in mind. Collect the data to the driver side, build it into a Pattern, and then BROADCAST it.
> I understand that the amount of data handled should be similar to Join-Like, but with better performance? (Because of avoiding duplicate construction of Pattern, and some other reasons?(*if you know the reasons, please enlighten me too*))

Spark-Version: `2.3.2` and `3.2.2` are available.

Comment: can you share the details of your fuzzy matches ? You can try writing regex and then perform joins on them,

Comment: @SarathChandraVema They are mostly some wildcard matches, e.g. (*.google.com, *.github.com). Do you mean to use Spark's rlike in Join? For example: `select a from tb1 join tb2 on tb1.a rlike tb2.b`